# Partition data by multiple partition keys - Azure ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have some data on on-prem SQL table. The data is huge ~100GB. The data many columns but two important ones are **d_type** and **d_date**.

d_type unique elements are **1,10,100** and **d_date ranges from 2022-01-01 - 2022-03-30**

I want to load this data into Azure using copy activity or dataflow but in a partitioned fashion, like the following format:

```
someDir/d_type=1/
                2022-01/somedata.parquet
                2022-02/somedata.parquet
                2022-03/somedata.parquet

someDir/d_type=10/
                2022-01/somedata.parquet
                2022-02/somedata.parquet
                2022-03/somedata.parquet


someDir/d_type=100/
                2022-01/somedata.parquet
                2022-02/somedata.parquet
                2022-03/somedata.parquet
```

I have tried with copy activity:

1. Copy activity can only use one partition key
2. If I partition by d_type, it creates parquet file with random bins i.e 1-20 (which contains only data for d_type=1), other file could have bins be 20-30 (which has no data)

Dataflow allows multiple partition keys, but I cannot use that sinceill have to copy the entrire data first from onprem sql to azure then process it. (As dataflow can only work with source link service which are linke via AzureIR and not SHIR).

Anyone got tips on how to solve this?

Comment: You can do this with data flows. You do not need to use self-hosted IR to connect to on-prem SQL. This is how you do that using Azure IR: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using custom python scripts because CopyActivity doesn't support partitions with multiple keys and we couldn't use the dataflow due to some business reasons as explained in the question.